# How to extract values from InputObject column in power shell?

Tags: powershell

I need to extract the row values listed under the InputObject column from a local variable.

I have local variable `$filtered_files` that contains list of file names and is defined under InputObject column and I am trying to get the file names only

$filtered_files will list below values

```
InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
File1.txt   =>

File2.txt   =>

log.txt     =>
```

Finally i need to get the file names as seen below and rest should excluded

`File1.txt`

`File2.txt`

`log.txt`

I tried with different post suggested, but nothing worked
Appreciate it if anyone can help on this?

Comment: `$filtered_files | select -expand inputobject` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since "InputObject" is a property name, you should be able to access it by simply using the dot notation: `$filtered_files.InputObject`

Comment: HI @Nathan,Thanks for the answer, but the above command give following output



Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name



----                -------------         ------ ----



-a----         8/6/2019   3:16 PM              0 File1.txt



-a----         8/6/2019   3:17 PM              0 File2.txt



-a----         8/6/2019   3:18 PM              0 log.txt


But i need to get only the file name listed as follows since i need to iterate on those to move  to another folder


File1.txt


File2.txt


log.txt

Comment: Can anyone please help on this? I need only to get only all File.txt value.  Appreciate if anyone can help on this

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for the above problem. As Nathan said, this  need to be iterated to get the InputObject value as show below

foreach($i in $filtered_files){Write-Host $i.InputObject}

Thank You